# Date format for AzureRmADAppCredential EndDate?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

I'm creating a powershell script that will deploy an Azure Automation Account to my resource group in order to create a Runbook which will automatically renew SSL certificates for Websites in the resource group.

In order for the Runbook to have access to my Azure resources, a service principal account is required. To create this I've been using the script from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-runas-account#create-run-as-account-using-powershell

Within CreateServicePrincipal function, a call is made to 
New-AzureRmADAppCredential, but it is constantly failing with the error:

```
New-AzureRmADAppCredential : Key credential end date is invalid.
```

I've decompiled the Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources DLL to have a look at what it's doing. It doesn't appear to take the parameter value into account whatsoever. I've tried several date format [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44794875/8435038) and everything seems to fail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The effective end date of the credential usage. The default end date value is one year from today. For an "asymmetric" type credential, this must be set to on or before the date that the X509 certificate is valid. Refer: [New-AzureRmADAppCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadappcredential?view=azurermps-6.0.0) 
You may try $validTo.AddDays(-1) in order to avoid the error. Refer [this blog](https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2016/11/15/azure-functions-access-keyvault-secrets-with-a-cert-secured-service-principal/) comments.

Comment: @AjayKadam I've already tried that, but haven't tried taking 2 days from the end date to see if it cures the problem... Thanks anyway.