# New-AzADApplication : Key credential end date is invalid. error in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Following are the powershell commands I am using from Azure Cloud Shell.

```
PS Azure:\> $keyCredential = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADKeyCredential
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> $keyCredential.StartDate = [System.DateTime]::Now
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> $keyCredential.EndDate = [System.DateTime]::Now.AddYears(1)
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> $keyCredential.KeyId = $keyId
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> $keyCredential.CertValue = $certBase64
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> $adApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "myorg-keyvault-monitor-ad-app" `
>>     -IdentifierUris "https://myorg.keyvault.com" `
>>     -HomePage "https://myorg.keyvault.com" `
>>     -KeyCredentials $keyCredential `
>>     -Verbose
```

I am getting the following error. **What could be the issue?** I tried the options mentioned in this post [Why am I getting "Key credential start date is invalid." trying to create a Active Directory Service Principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792762/why-am-i-getting-key-credential-start-date-is-invalid-trying-to-create-a-acti) but still getting the same error.

```
VERBOSE: No value specified for -EndDate parameter; setting the value to one year after start date.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Adding a new application with display name 'myorg-keyvault-monitor-ad-app'" on target "myorg-keyvault-monitor-ad-app".
New-AzADApplication : Key credential end date is invalid.
At line:1 char:10
+ $adApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "myorg-keyvault-monitor-ad- ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-AzADApplication], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.NewAzureADApplicationCommand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, the issue was caused by you set the `EndDate` after the date that the X509 certificate is valid, for an `asymmetric` type credential, we need to set it before the valid date.

To fix the issue, change the `$keyCredential.EndDate`, you could refer to my complete sample.

```
$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cer.Import("C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\test123.cer")
$binCert = $cer.GetRawCertData()
$credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binCert)

$keyCredential = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADKeyCredential
$keyCredential.StartDate = [System.DateTime]::Now
$keyCredential.EndDate = $cer.NotAfter
$keyCredential.KeyId = "<guid>"
$keyCredential.CertValue = $credValue
$adApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "testapp3" -IdentifierUris "https://myorg.keyvault.com" -HomePage "https://myorg.keyvault.com" -KeyCredentials $keyCredential -Verbose
```

[image]

Comment: I get the following error when i try that : $keyCredential.EndDate = $cert.NotAfter
Exception setting "EndDate": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:1 char:1
+ $keyCredential.EndDate = $cert.NotAfter
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

Comment: Turn out, i was using X509Certificate instead of X509Certificate2. Changing to X509Certificate2 fixed the issue.